# Enumerating an uncountable graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> **Proposition 1.4.1.** The vertices of a connected graph $G$ can always be enumerated, say as $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$, so that $G_{i}:=G\left[v_{1}, \ldots, v_{i}\right]$ is connected for every $i$.
>
> Proof. Pick any vertex as $v_{1}$, and assume inductively that $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{i}$ have been chosen for some $i<|G|$. Now pick a vertex $v \in G-G_{i}$. As $G$ is connected, it contains a $v-v_{1}$ path $P$. Choose as $v_{i+1}$ the last vertex of $P$ in $G-G_{i}$; then $v_{i+1}$ has a neighbour in $G_{i}$. The connectedness of every $G_{i}$ follows by induction on $i$.

In my interpretation, this theorem is saying that we can grow out a connected graph from an original starting position one by one. What happens if there are uncountably many nodes? Would this enumeration still be possible?

Comment: In many contexts graphs are implicitly assumed to be finite. Countably infinite graphs occur e.g. in group theory but examples with bigger cardinality than that are rare.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan When one is a descriptive set theorist, taking symmetric subsets of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and calling them "graphs" is a way of life. ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it requires the use of [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction). As is usually the case, this is not *hard*, but requires slightly more care than induction in the finite case.

We induct up to $|G| = \eta$. Enumerate the vertices of $G$ as $\{ v_\alpha \mid \alpha < \eta \}$.

We let $G_1 = \{ v_0 \}$.

At successor stages, we define $G_{\alpha + 1}$ as follows. Since $G$ is connected, there's a path $p$ from $v_{\alpha}$ to $v_0$. Let $G_{\alpha + 1}$ be $G_\alpha$ plus all the vertices in $p$.
Notice $G_{\alpha+1}$ is connected and contains $v_{\alpha}$ (since $G_\alpha$ was connected by construction, and we added the entire path from $v_0$ to $v_\alpha$).

At limit stages, we define $G_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} G_\alpha$. This is still connected, since every $v_\beta \in G_\lambda$ must have been added in one of the stages before $\lambda$, and thus has a path to $v_0$ by induction. Also, again by induction, $G_\lambda$ contains all the vertices $v_\alpha$ with $\alpha < \lambda$.

Then this sequence of graphs $(G_\alpha)$ does what you want. If it's important that $G_{\alpha + 1}$ has exactly one more vertex than $G_\alpha$, you can modify this construction to add the path from $v_0$ to $v_\alpha$ one vertex at a time. This makes the indexing more annoying, but there's no other complications.

---

I hope this helps ^_^